# stackengine subscript size

Tags: stackengine

Correct subscript size not taken using stackengine package, please find MWE file is as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\Utildesim}[1]{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1pt}{#1}{\sim}{U}{c}{F}{F}{S}}\vphantom{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent{}${\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}} (x )$and the symbol $\mu _{\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}} (x )$ is the degree of membership of element \textit{x} in fuzzy set $\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}$. Therefore, $\mu _{\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}} (x )$ is a value on the unit interval that measures the degree to which element \textit{x} belongs to fuzzy set $\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}$; equivalently, $\mu _{\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}} (x )$ = degree to which $x\in \protect\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `\undertilde` command from `accents`?

Comment: accents package not exactly centered to the character that why I choose stackengine package.

Comment: Package used \usepackage{accents}\usepackage{stix} TeX code: \noindent{}${\underaccent{\sim}{\mathrm{A}}} (x )$

Comment: You can add a small correction, like this: `${\underaccent{\,sim}{\mathrm{A}}} (x )$`.

Comment: Is there any other option to control macro itself, in my books, there were almost ~1000 occurrences with different character.

Comment: I don't know any (but I'm not a specialist). Does this default happen for all characters? Also, you might use a regex  Search and Replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that `stackengine` does not preserve the math style that is current at the time of invocation.  One solution is to additionally use features of the `scalerel` package (namely `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}`) to save and restore the current math style where needed inside the stack.

Additionally, I set the stack gap to `1\LMpt`, which, inside of a `\ThisStyle`, is set to a nominal value of 1pt, but scaled to the size of the current math style.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand{\Utildesim}[1]{\ThisStyle{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1\LMpt}{\SavedStyle#1}{\SavedStyle\sim}
  {U}{c}{F}{F}{S}}\vphantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent{}${\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}} (x )$and the symbol $\mu _{\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}} (x )$ is the degree of membership of element \textit{x} in fuzzy set $\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}$. Therefore, $\mu _{\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}} (x )$ is a value on the unit interval that measures the degree to which element \textit{x} belongs to fuzzy set $\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}$; equivalently, $\mu _{\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}} (x )$ = degree to which $x\in \protect\Utildesim{\mathrm{A}}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent Answer, Thank you, Segletes.

Comment: @RajeshN You are welcome. You will find the `\ThisStyle` approach can be very useful for importing the current math style into places where it is otherwise lost, such as boxes and stacks.  I have a lot of answers on this site which use the scalerel/stackengine combination in this way.